# Can I do a datetime plot in Highcharts when only some of my measurements have time data?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to do a datetime chart in Highcharts, but only some of my measurements have a time associated with them. For example, one part of my data might look like this:

> 1,00:1C:05:00:3F:76,hrsp,79,97,000010000
>
> 1,00:1C:05:00:3F:76,hrsp,79,97,000010000
>
> 1,00:1C:05:00:3F:76,time,7,11,1,22,10,16
>
> 1,00:1C:05:00:3F:76,hrsp,80,97,000010000
>
> 1,00:1C:05:00:3F:76,hrsp,80,97,000010000
>
> 1,00:1C:05:00:3F:76,time,7,11,1,22,10,46
>
> 1,00:1C:05:00:3F:76,hrsp,70,97,000010000

and so on, with the lines labeled hrsp being data measurements. In my actual data, every thirtieth line is a time measurement. What I've been trying is to associate every time measurement with the data immediately before it, and plot those on a datetime chart, but I can't figure out how to have the unknown time measurements between them put on the same chart.

Is it possible to set up the chart to show the measurements that do have time data, and just evenly space the remaining ones between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the answer is No, you need to process your data when updating the chart.